# Large arithmetic calculator?

Tags: calculator

I am looking for an (online) calculator that can compute millions of digits (maybe a billion) without slowing my computer down and would perform these exact computations:

Round[$2^{2^{24.0193819506}}$]; the full decimal expansion (not just an approximation), and other computations like this one.

Does anyone know of an (presumably online) tool I can use for these exact computations? Thanks.

Comment: Might want to look into cloud computing.

Comment: For example https://cloud.sagemath.com/

Comment: Why do you think your example computation would require "millions of digits" (whatever you might mean by that) to calculate exactly?

Comment: @ChasBrown Because $2^{24}$ is greater than 16.7 million, so $2^{2^{24}}$ literally has over 5 million digits.  OP is looking for an online calculator, with enough internal precision to be able to compute exact values of this type.  I don't see anything confusing about that.